# How to write google cloud storage node getFiles to file?

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-storage

The following code results a file with content Object Object. Can you please point what I'm missing here?

```
gcs.bucket(xxx).getFiles()
        .then(results => {
            const files = results[0];
            files.forEach(file => {
                if(file.name === 'xxx'){
                    fs.writeFile("xxx", file, function(err) {
                        if(err) {
                            return console.log(err);
                        }

                        console.log("The file was saved!");
                    });
                    res.end()
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('ERROR:', err);
        });
```

Comment: Look at the *Downloading a File* example on https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/File ... if you have trouble understanding the `event` based architecture and can't get it to work for you then let me know. I would convert the events to a basic promise... that way you get the benefits of streaming but still an easy way to process all the files...unless you don't care when they all finish.

Comment: Thanks Cody. I was trying the download api and it was resulting in an empty file. gcs.bucket.file('icons.json').download({
        destination: 'icons.json'
    },err => {)});  
This getFiles method is giving me a big object that has nothing to do with the content of the file I'm trying to fetch. I was hoping there is a hidden method in it that gives the file content.

Comment: Don't use the callback if you're using it as a promise maybe, `gcs.bucket.file('icons.json').download({ destination: 'icons.json' }).then(downloadResponse=>{});`

Comment: It should return a `https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/global#DownloadResponse` which should just be the contents of the file...

Comment: Thanks Cody! You just ended two days of misery!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the callback if you're using it as a promise maybe,

```
gcs.bucket.file('icons.json').download({ destination: 'icons.json' }).then(downloadResponse=>{});
```

Comment: I'm getting a json file that is not my file. 
{"domain":null,"_events":{},"_eventsCount":0,"metadata":{"kind":"storage#object","id":"....
I was hoping that there is a method like file.content that gives the actual file content.